# Natively running Firefox on Wayland in Ubuntu (not xwayland)

Tags: package-management, firefox, snap, wayland

is there any effort to get wayland support for Firefox in Ubuntu? This seems to be going to be default in next Fedora, so it should be stable enought.

I'd rather avoid yet another package manager on my system, so apt or snap would be prefered to flatpack...

Any pointer will be appreciated.
Thanks,
Franck

Comment: firefox-wayland's  not complete yet for use as the default and past the deadline for the F30 release, but still may be allowed in if it doesn't delay the beta.  Soon, maybe.  https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Wayland-Firefox-F30-More-Time